# Draw rectangulars in a confusion matrix using geom_rect()

Tags: r, ggplot2, matrix

I have created a confusion matrix using the following code:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = Predicted, y = Actual)) +
geom_tile(aes(fill = Percentage), alpha = .8) +
geom_text(aes(label = Percentage), color = "white") +
scale_fill_gradientn(colours = rev(brewer.pal(5, "Spectral")), limits = c(0, 100)) +
scale_x_discrete(position = "top")
```

I would like to draw black rectangulars around 95% and 100%.

Thanks
[image: Confusion matrix]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add this line after the first `geom_tile`

```
  geom_tile(aes(x = Predicted, y = Actual),
            data=data[data$Predicted == data$Actual, ], size=1, color="black", fill = 'transparent') +
```

Full code:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = Predicted, y = Actual)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = Percentage), alpha = .8) +
  geom_tile(aes(x = Predicted, y = Actual),
            data=data[data$Predicted == data$Actual, ], size=1, color="black", fill = 'transparent') +
  geom_text(aes(label = Percentage), color = "white") +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = rev(brewer.pal(5, "Spectral")), limits = c(0, 100)) +
  scale_x_discrete(position = "top")
```